# Get value of 2nd Column of table and then graph it Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, graph

I'm trying to create a graph from values I get from the https://financialmodelingprep.com/ API. Basically what I did so far is that I create a table with all the values like this:

```
function myFunction() { 
      var symbol =  
              document.getElementById("Ticker").value; 


//var symbol = "TSLA";





  // https://financialmodelingprep.com/developer/docs
  getRequest(
    'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/financials/income-statement/' + symbol + '?period=quarter',
    drawOutput
  );

  function drawOutput(responseText) {
    let resp = JSON.parse(responseText).financials;
    let financials = resp;
    let $table = document.createElement("table");
    $table.className += " table2";

    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.stock-name')[0];

    let $head = document.createElement("thead");
    let $body = document.createElement("tbody");

    let $lineHader = document.createElement("tr");

 /*    let $elefirst = document.createElement("th");
    $elefirst.textContent = 'Fiscal';
    $lineHader.appendChild($elefirst); */

    for (let i = 0; i < financials.length; i++) {
      let financial = financials[i];
      let $line = document.createElement("tr");


      for (var key in financial) {
        if (i === 0 && financial.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          let $ele = document.createElement("th");
          $ele.textContent = key;
          $lineHader.appendChild($ele);
        }
      }

      $head.appendChild($lineHader);
      $table.appendChild($head);
      var z = 0;
      for (var key2 in financial) {
        if (financial.hasOwnProperty(key2)) {
       /*    if (z === 0) {
            let title = Object.keys(resp)[i];
            let $eleTile = document.createElement("td");
            $eleTile.textContent = title;
            $line.appendChild($eleTile);
          } */
          let $eletd = document.createElement("td");
          if (z === 0) {
            $eletd.textContent = financial[key2];
          } else {
            $eletd.textContent = financial[key2];
          }
          $line.appendChild($eletd);
        }
        z++;
      }
      $body.appendChild($line)

      $table.appendChild($body);

    }

    document.body.appendChild($table);
  }

  function getRequest(url, success) {
    var req = false;
    try {
      req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
      try {
        req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (e) {
        try {
          req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    if (!req) return false;
    if (typeof success != 'function') success = function() {};
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (req.readyState == 4) {
        if (req.status === 200) {
          success(req.responseText)
        }
      }
    }
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.send(null);
    return req;
  }

}
</script>
<div class="stock-name"></div>
```

Which will look something like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoX0X.png)
What I'm trying to do is to get the 2nd Column so the Revenue and graph those values with this:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');


var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [2, 1, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            fill: false,
            showLine: true,
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]


        }

    }
});
```

And basically plug in the Revenue to the data values which are currently 2, 1, 3, 5, 2, 3 . I would appreciate any help possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can help you fetch the second row but not graphing it.
For this to work, your table needs to be in the html, and you need to add an id to the table like so:

```
$table.id = "chartTable";
```

Put this after the `let $table = createElement()` or whatever.
Then:

```
let secondRow = document.querySelectorAll('#' + $table.id + ' tr')[1].;
```

**Edit**: 
For columns:

```
let rows = document.querySelectorAll('#' + $table.id + ' tr'), i, col = [];
for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  let row = rows[i][1];
  col.push(row.innerText);
}
```

Then the `col` array would contain all the values.

**Explanation** (for the columns bit):
To access the second column, you need to access the second value of each row.

**Second Edit:**

```
let tds = document.querySelectorAll('#' + $table.id + ' tr td'), i, col = [];
let l = 20; // l is the number of elements in a **row**
for (i = 1; i < tds.length; i += l) {
  col.push(tds[i].innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for answering the question I accidentally said row instead of column.

Comment: Ok then. Editing.

Comment: By the way, the `$table` must still have an ID.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer but now I get the error TypeError: row is undefined when trying to run it.

Comment: `row` or `rows`? Also, they are both defined so no problem should be caused. Did you make sure that the `table` has an id?

Comment: Yes table still has the id chartTable and it says that is the error has something to do with this line: col.push(row.innerText);

Comment: Hey thanks again but it now works but when I log col the output is not the Revenue values but instead. 
"-1": undefined
length: 0
<prototype>: Array []

Comment: Oh, yeah, right. Edited. Try the the `second edit` again.

Comment: Thanks again but there is a problem again. The values values returned are kind of all over the place and not the only the ones from the second column. Thank you so much for taking your time and helping me :D

Comment: If you have more or less than 20 elements in a row, change `l` to that number.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it

Comment: One last question how would I change that to be from oldest to newest since its currently from newest to oldest value.

Comment: And what would I need to change to make it not be column 2 but for example column 3

Comment: `col = col.reverse()` after the loop.

Comment: Thanks and how would I for example do this for the 3rd column instead of the 2nd

Comment: Which column relies on the `for` loop. Check the `i = 1` part. `i` needs to be the number of the column - 1. I put `1` because it's `2 - 1`. You need to put `2` as it is `3 - 1`. Basically, change `i = 1` to `i = 2`.

Comment: Hey I just tried the col = col.reverse and that doesn't work like its supposed to.

Comment: Add this code: `let reversed = []; for (let j = col.length; j > -1; j--) {reversed.push(col[j])}`. Reversed is the new array.